# Thunderbird: change "selected" tags background color

Tags: thunderbird

I have defined tags, with colors:

```
grep 'mailnews.tags.' prefs.js
user_pref("mailnews.tags.test.color", "#f2a064");
user_pref("mailnews.tags.test.tag", "TEST");
user_pref("mailnews.tags.lists.color", "#3baff4");
user_pref("mailnews.tags.lists.tag", "lists");
```

When message is tagged, the text has the color as defined above. But when I move around with the cursor, selected tagged message now has this color (or its derivative) used as backgroung color, with white text. This makes the tag unreadable when the tag color is also light tone.

I have tried this in my **userChrome.css**:

```css
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(lc-F2A064, selected) {
    background-color: #B63C29 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(lc-F2A064, selected) {
    color: #F7FF7C !important;
}

treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(lc-3BAFF4, selected) {
    background-color: #B63C29 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(lc-3BAFF4, selected) {
    color: #F7FF7C !important;
}
```

but this seems to have no effect.

I am using Thunderbird `68.8` on Debian.

So, in short, I know how to define tag text color. But how do I define the background color when tagged message is selected (cursor currently on message)?

Comment: Why is this specific to Linux and Unix machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags are no longer referred to by an "lc-" prefixed color value.

The first five tags are referred to as `T_24label#`, where `#` is the number of the tag. For example, the default "Important" tag is referred to as `T_24label1`. (In my experience, the first five tags are referred to as above even if they've been renamed from their defaults.)

Beyond the fifth, tags are referred to by their names in lowercase prefixed by a `T`. For example, a tag named "Tech" is referred to as `Ttech`. However, it's not clear if it's possible to refer to tags with names that include spaces, such as "New Message" or "Very Important".

The info above was distilled from the collection of replies (*not* the "Chosen solution") to the Mozilla Support post [Tags : colorize background instead of text](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1270814).

As an example, here's my entire **userChrome.css** file:

```css
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected) {
    background-color: lightgrey !important;
    color: black !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(selected, focus) {
    background-color: Highlight !important;
    color: white !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row {
    border: none !important;
    background-color: white !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected) {
    background-color: lightgrey !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(selected, focus) {
    background-color: Highlight !important;
}

/* Tag Important */
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(T_24label1) {
    background-color: #BF4040 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(T_24label1, selected) {
    background-color: #FFCCCC !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(T_24label1, selected, focus) {
    background-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label1) {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label1, selected) {
    background-color: #FFCCCC !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label1, selected, focus) {
    background-color: #FF0000 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
}

/* Tag Financial */
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(T_24label3) {
    background-color: #1A5B1A !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(T_24label3) {
    color: #FFF !important;
}

/* Tag Tech (9th tag) */
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(Ttech) {
    background-color: #339999 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(Ttech, selected) {
    background-color: #1aeaea !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(Ttech, selected, focus) {
    background-color: #32c7c7 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(Ttech) {
    color: #FFF !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(Ttech, selected) {
    background-color: #1aeaea !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(Ttech, selected, focus) {
    background-color: #32c7c7 !important;
    color: #FFF !important;
}
```

And, referring to the tag `TEST` in the question's defined tags, here's a **minimal** working example:

```
treechildren::-moz-tree-row(Ttest, selected) {
    background-color: #B63C29 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(Ttest, selected) {
    background-color: #B63C29 !important;
}
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text(Ttest, selected) {
    background-color: #B63C29 !important;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a working example? I tried copying code from the linked Mozilla Support post, but that does not work for me.

Comment: can you please provide **minimal** working example, of just the relevant lines ? Just show me how to change background of `tag1` when selected, without changing anything else.

Comment: I found out why your example did not work before in my setting. My tag names start with uppercase, so I was using uppercase in the tag name. that did not work. It works now when I use lowercase, ie `Ttest`, instead of `TTest`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a little more complicated than that, and you actually *can* deal with tags whose text contains spaces.

open about:config and search for "mailnews.tags". You will see things like "mainnews.tags.custom.color and mailnews.tags.custom.tag

The pattern is mailnews.tags.XXX.color and mailnews.tags.XXX.tag

You use the value TXXX in your CSS.  However, if XXX is like $labelN you use "T_24labelN"

If seems that, if there is a space when you create the tag, it seems to do different things depending on the version of TB you were using when you created it.  I have an old one that uses the pattern $labelN and I have a new one that just uses an underscore where the space would be.

Be aware that if you change the actual tag text/value, the "XXX" part of mailnews.tag.XXX.color and mailnews.tags.XXX.tag will *NOT* change.  Say you originally created a tag using "custom", then later change the tag text from "custom" to "whatever", you still use "Tcustom", *NOT* "Twhatever".  The config entries are still mailnews.tag.custom.color and mailnews.tag.custom.tag.  Only the VALUE of mailnews.tag.custom.tag changes.

Of course, I might have some of this a bit wrong, and the developers can change things whenever they feel a need to.